# Hadoop imports cannot be resolved in eclipse

Tags: hadoop

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
```

Learning hadoop programming from scratch.
I have written above line of code  in eclipse.
it is showing error as "import org.apache.hadoop.io. cannot be resolved.".
I have already added external jar file "Hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3,jar" 
Is there anything else to add ?

Comment: If probably recommend using Maven to manage hadoop dependencies. Dealing with JAR files is a pain

Answer (score 0):

In your all the dependents jar needs to be added, a single jar file wont help.

Try Using Maven.

Dependency is available on below link.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

1) Convert the project to a maven project if it's not yet.**Project>Configure>Convert to maven project.**
2)Add this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

This should resolve your errors. This worked for me!